# how to create a single database for one app, to be shared through all users that uses the same app?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I will design one android application that is installed on different virtual devices that share the same database! Other tables are shared as well such as recipes, user information, etc

1) Anyways my question is for example "if user A created a new recipe and wants to share it with user B " how is this possible? is there any trick with the database design

2) Or should I just let every application have their own database, then use web service to share the common tables between the applications?

Comment: Your second solution would be the one -- you need to have a shared service in the middle. If it's just a very small user-base, you can use services like FireBase for this.

Comment: I know but I don't think that firebase supports images for java api, the only do for javascript

Comment: You realize that you never mentioned images in your question, yes?

Comment: After searching I found that firebase supports image after encode them to base64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a web service that manages the data transfer among the users' databases.

The best way to do this is to create the database on server side and use it through APIs.

Comment: As I said, It's better to create your database on server side, And write APIs for the basic operations you want to implement. You will send data as parameters, and receive them in JSON, XML, or whatever format you prefer.